# Does asp.net ajax pageLoad fires for each user control on my page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have 4 user control in my page. Will asp.net ajax pageLoad method fire for each of these usercontrol or only once for the page?

Answer (score 0):

If the user controls are inside `UpdatePanel`, than their `Load` method will be called otherwise not. 
While `PageLoad` method is called any way.